# Ionic 4 Firebase.h file not found in MAC OS

Tags: macos, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm building an APP where I need to use the FCM ionic plugin for push sending, I did it on Android and it worked normal, when I'm going to the Mac it is giving me the following errors ** 'Firebase.h' file not found ** I did several procedure that I found on the internet and I can't solve it.

**Meu arquivo prodfile**

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'APVS Área do Associado' do
    use_frameworks!

    project 'APVS Área do Associado.xcodeproj'

    pod 'Firebase/Core'

end
```

**pod install**

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing Firebase (6.16.0)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics (6.2.2)
Installing FirebaseCore (6.6.1)
Installing FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (1.2.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop (1.2.0)
Installing FirebaseInstallations (1.1.0)
Installing FirebaseInstanceID (4.3.0)
Installing GoogleAppMeasurement (6.2.2)
Installing GoogleDataTransport (3.3.1)
Installing GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport (1.3.1)
Installing GoogleUtilities (6.5.1)
Installing PromisesObjC (1.2.8)
Installing nanopb (0.3.9011)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 13 total pods installed.
```

After the installation I open the file as informed in other answers by running *.xcworkspace but even so the error remains if someone has already been through this and managed to solve it?

I thank you for your understanding!

**Ionic Info**

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.15 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.7.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.23
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : browser 6.0.0, ios 5.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1, (and 15 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res                          : not installed
   native-run (update available: 0.3.0) : 0.2.8

System:

   ios-sim : 8.0.2
   NodeJS  : v10.16.3 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm     : 6.13.6
   OS      : macOS Catalina
   Xcode   : Xcode 11.0 Build version 11A420a
```